# How to use jQuery DataTable to display items data from the database based on user_id selected from modal in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, model-view-controller, datatable, laravel-blade

I have a form that takes user_id as an input from a dataTable selected from a modal using jquery.
When I click search, a datatable should be populated with data from items table where items.owner_id is the user_id in the textfield.

Controller: WithdrawByUserController

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data['items']=Item::all()->where('status','=','in-use');
        $data['owners'] = Owner::whereIn('id', $data['items']->pluck('owner_id')->unique())->get();
        $selectedUser = $request->input('user_id'); //This is coming from the form data
        $data['selectedItems'] = Item::where('owner_id',$selectedUser)->get(); // This is what I want to display
        return view('transactions.withdrawByUser.create')->with($data);
    }
```

The Blade

```
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="user">Select User</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" class="form-control" aria-label="User Name" readonly value="">
                                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="user_id" hidden>User</label>
                                                <div class="input-group" >
{{--                                                    The user_id is retrieved here from the Modal. The ID is the value that is selected from the DataTable Modal--}}
                                                    <input type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id" class="form-control" aria-label="User">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <label for="search" style="color: white">Search</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="searchItems" id="searchItems">Search</button>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="userModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select User</h5>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
{{--                                                        This Modal pops up when the Search Icon is clicked--}}
                                                        <table id="userTableModal" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-sm text-xs" >
                                                            <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                                <th>Entity</th>
                                                                <th>Site</th>
                                                                <th>Department</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                            @foreach($owners as $row)
                                                                <tr>
{{--                                                                    Following button passes the value to the user_id textfield using js--}}
                                                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="user_id-btn" data-dismiss="modal">{{ $row->id }}</button></td>
                                                                    <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ $row->entity->name }}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ $row->site->name }}</td>
                                                                    <td>{{ $row->department->name }}</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            @endforeach
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        {{--                                    itemModal starts--}}

                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class = "row">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <table id="itemsDataTableIndex2" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-xs text-xs" >
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" value="true">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>ID</th>
                                                    <th>Item Name</th>
                                                    <th>Item Description</th>
                                                    <th>Item Type</th>
                                                    <th>Purchase date</th>
                                                    <th>Serial No.</th>
                                                    <th>Issue Date</th>
                                                    <th>Purchase Value</th>

                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
{{--                                                I want to populate the following data where the selected user_id is the owner_id field of the items--}}
                                                <tbody>
                                                @foreach($selectedItems as $row)
                                                    @if($row->owner_id)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkMultiple" name="checkMultiple" value="true">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->description }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->code['comment'] }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->purchase_date }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->serial_no }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->issue_date }}</td>
                                                        <td>{{ $row->purchase_value }}</td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                    @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "row">
                                        <div class = "col-lg-12">
                                            <div class = "form-group">
                                                <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="remarks" id = "remarks" class="form-control" value="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div><!-- /.card-body -->
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right subbtn " name="subbtn">
                                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Create
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        $('#userTableModal tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
            var userId = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().trim();
            var userName = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim();
            // var ownerName = $(this).find('td:eq(7)').text().trim();

            $("#user_id").val(userId);
            $("#user").val(userName);
            // $("#owner_name").val(ownerName);
        });
    </script>
```

[[user_id is selected here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dtAq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFoyx.jpg)
[This is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4p56.jpg)

I tried to populate the table using ajax response.
What I am trying to achieve,
When the user_id is selected, I want to populate the dataTable with items data from items table where user_id is the owner_id.